# dplyr output is "large dtplyr_step_group"

Tags: r, dplyr

My apologies, I had a script that was doing this, then I restarted my system, and the problem stopped. So...I can't recreate my problem. Nonetheless, I'd certainly like to know more about what this is.

I read in a fairly-large (>100M-row) dataframe using 'fread'.

I then used a dplyr chain to process the data and make a few calculations

`DT %>% dplyr::group_by(<variables) %>% dplyr::summarize(<calculations>)`

My output is usually a dataframe (or, a tibble, I think). This time, however, the output was a list. It was labeled as "large dtyplyr_step_group". As a result, I couldn't proceed with the rest of my code (I had other calculations I wanted to perform). I kept getting errors that the dataframe I was trying to use as an input wasn't really a dataframe.

I've googled this term to figure out what this is, and have gotten nowhere. I've dabbled in using dtplyr, but I kinda thought I had to specifically call the drplyr::lazy_dt() before any grouping/summarizing for it to take effect. This seems to have done it automatically.

So, I guess I have 2 questions:

1. by reading in my data with `fread` instead of `read.csv`, did I make DF into a format that was as if I ran dtplyr::lazy_dt()?
2. what is "large dtplyr_step_group", and how can I move forward with it? I have other calculations to do that aren't part of the chain (Ex: 'cut', 'min', 'max'), but when I try to run these commands I receive an error because my input is not a data.frame.

Comment: When you use `fread`, you get a data.table, unless you use the `data.table = FALSE` argument. When you have loaded the `dtplyr` package and use a `dplyr` verb on a `data.table` object, it automatically converts the input to a `lazy_dt` if the input is a data.table. There is nothing you can do about this, except to not load `dtplyr` to begin with (even unloading does not work, the conversion still happens). If you're fine with this and just want the output as a tibble when you're done, just add a `%>% collect()` to the end.

Comment: A `dtplyr_step_[group/subset/etc.]` is some data.table code translated from your dplyr pipeline by dtplyr that has not yet been executed to create the output table. The way dtplyr works is that you have to put `%>% collect()` as the last step to get your output.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for!